# Converting HTML to WordPress but CSS doesn't output

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am converting an HTML & CSS with bits of JS into a WordPress theme. Just a newbie with this practice. I watched and read tutorials. I followed their way. But in this code, the CSS of the WordPress theme doesn't function. I don't know the problem. I used 'inspect element' to see the problem. But it doesn't read the CSS file so that's the problem. But I already included the `style.css` in the header. What seems to be the problem here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />

  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
  <script src="js/wow/wow.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {       
      if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) {
        new WOW().init();
      }   
    });
  </script>

  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
       <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
     </a>
  </div>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
  <![endif]-->

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#owl").owlCarousel({
      items : 1, //10 items above 1000px browser width
      itemsDesktop : [995,1], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
      itemsDesktopSmall : [767, 1], // betweem 900px and 601px
      itemsTablet: [700, 1], //2 items between 600 and 0
      itemsMobile : [479, 1], // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
      navigation : true,
      pagination :  false
    });
  });  
  </script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

  <body class="page1" id="top">
    <div class="main">
  <!--==============================
                header
  =================================-->
      <header class="">  
         <!--==============================
                    Stuck menu
        =================================-->
        <section id="stuck_container">

          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="grid_10">

                <h1>
                  <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo alt"></a>
                </h1>

                <div class="navigation">
                  <nav>
                    <ul class="sf-menu">
                      <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index-1.html">About</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="index-2.html">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index-3.html">Projects</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index-4.html">Blog</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index-5.html">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section> 

      </header>
```

Comment: checked for any console errors?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. It doesn't have any errors. Maybe because, it doesn't read the css file.

Comment: It should have given `404` error if the CSS was not able to find because of the relative path you have given. Check what gets as rendered html in your page for your `link`

Comment: I activated the 'log network access' in "web console" and there were errors like '404 not found' in some css, js, and image files using request method GET.

Comment: Do you purposely have grid.css and animate.css commented out?

Comment: Yes, because in style.css, it is already included using import.

Comment: I included the get_template_directory_uri() on every css, image, and js but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles should be enqueued in the functions.php file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 2):

Like JeremyE said, the "WordPress-way" to include JavaScript and CSS assets in a theme is using the `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` functions. WPBeginner has a [great tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) on how to do it.

But, the issue with your code is this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
```

`get_template_directory_uri` returns the template URL, but does not echo it. Update the line to this to make it work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
```